When using Voiceover and press the letter h without any other keys it does header search
When using voiceover - the built in screenreader on the mac - it behaves as it other keys of the keyboard are pressed at the same time, but they aren't.
For example pressing the letter h on the keyboard is behaving as though I entered VO+Command+H next headline, but when I turn off voiceover and press the letter h it is a lower case h.
When I press the letter l it acts as though I entered VO+Command+L which is the command to go to the next link, but when I turn off voiceover and type l it is not an upper case l that comes out.
When I have voiceover off and press the f5 function key it does not act as though command is pressed at the same time and turn on voiceover, thus it seems like only when voiceover is on that my keyboard acts as though the control, option and command keys are pressed with every key I press.
What can do this?
